# c++ : printing wired string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm converting a `string` to `char` array and than back to a `string` and into a `vector`.
When I'm trying to print I'm getting this:

```
this
is
the
sentence iuִִ[nu@h?(h????X
```

and much more. This is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    string s ="this is the sentence";
    char seq[sizeof(s)];
    strcpy(seq, "this is the sentence");
    vector<string> vec = split(seq);
    printWords(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the func.cpp file. One function splits the char to string vector, the other is printing:

```
vector<string> split(char sentence[]){
    vector<string> vecto;
    int i=0;
    int size= strlen(sentence);
    while((unsigned)i< size){
        string s;
        char c =' ';
        while(sentence[i]!=c){
            s=s+sentence[i];
            i+=1;
        }
        vecto.push_back(s);

        i+=1;
    }

    return vecto;
}

void printWords(vector<string> words){
    int i=0;
    while ((unsigned)i<words.size()){
        string s = words.at(i);
        cout << words.at(i) << endl;
        i+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `s.length()` or `s.size()`, not `sizeof(s)`. `sizeof(s)` is the size, in bytes, of `std::string`. Also account for the null.

Comment: changed it... still getting same error. for char array what do i use? strln ?

Comment: Yes, use `strlen` for a C string. Anyway, you're also going out of bounds on the string you pass into `split`. It looks for a space until it finds one, even past the end of the string, before quitting. That can be fixed by checking for null as well.

Comment: By the way, why do you call it wired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding the answer above, try a less error-prone style, something more like this (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){
  string s{"this is the sentence"};
  stringstream sStream;
  sStream<<s;
  string word;
  vector<string> vec;
  while(sStream >> word){
    vec.emplace_back(word);
  }
  for(auto &w : vec){
    cout << "a word: " << w <<endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your issues is that `sizeof(s) != s.size()`.

Try this:

```
char letters = new char[s.size() + 1]; // +1 for the null terminator.
```

The expression `sizeof(s)` returns the size of the `std::string` object, not the quantity of characters in the string.  The `std::string` object may be more than the string contents.

Also, try using `std::string::operator[]` to access individual characters in the string.

**Example:**

```
string s = "this is it";
char c = s[5]; // returns 'i' from "is".
```

You should also consider using the search functions of `std::string`, such as `std::string::find_first_of`.

**Example:**

unsigned int position = s.find_first_of(' ');

Another useful function is the `substr` method:

```
   std::string word = s.substr(0, position);
```

Comment: still getting the same result. maybe its the strln() ?

Comment: its working! the problem was on this row:     while(sentence[i]!=c){
its was going out of bounds. thanx u all!